# Java Regex to match multiple lines

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Following is Sample the data on which regex should be applied:

```
2019-05-27 10:49:18,418 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Filter -> Map (1/1) (824780055001546646d35df7a64cfe3c) switched from CANCELING to CANCELED.
2019-05-27 10:49:18,418 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Try to restart or fail the job  (3064130e1dccead0b037f193d3699c3b) if no longer possible.
2019-05-27 10:49:18,418 ERROR  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Job  (3064130e1dccead0b037f193d3699c3b) switched from state FAILING to FAILED.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: json can not be null or empty
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.Utils.notEmpty(Utils.java:256)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.compile(JsonPath.java:424)
    at com.mypkg.subpkg.ControlData$ConnectedStreams.validateJsonPath(ControlData.java:194)
    at com.mypkg.subpkg.ControlData$ConnectedStreams.flatMap1(ControlData.java:178)
    at com.mypkg.subpkg.ControlData$ConnectedStreams.flatMap1(ControlData.java:171)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.co.CoStreamFlatMap.processElement1(CoStreamFlatMap.java:53)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor.processInput(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:238)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.TwoInputStreamTask.run(TwoInputStreamTask.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:300)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-05-27 10:49:18,418 ERROR  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Could not restart the job  (3064130e1dccead0b037f193d3699c3b) because the restart strategy prevented it.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: json can not be null or empty
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.Utils.notEmpty(Utils.java:256)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.compile(JsonPath.java:424)
    at com.mypkg.subpkg.ControlData$ConnectedStreams.validateJsonPath(ControlData.java:194)
    at com.mypkg.subpkg.ControlData$ConnectedStreams.flatMap1(ControlData.java:178)
    at com.mypkg.subpkg.ControlData$ConnectedStreams.flatMap1(ControlData.java:171)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.co.CoStreamFlatMap.processElement1(CoStreamFlatMap.java:53)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor.processInput(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:238)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.TwoInputStreamTask.run(TwoInputStreamTask.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:300)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-05-27 10:49:18,418 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Stopping checkpoint coordinator for job 3064130e1dccead0b037f193d3699c3b.
2019-05-27 10:49:18,418 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.StandaloneCompletedCheckpointStore  - Shutting down
2019-05-27 10:49:18,419 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher      - Job 3064130e1dccead0b037f193d3699c3b reached globally terminal state FAILED.
```

Basically what I want to extract is time stamp and ERROR with message:

For an instance:

```
TimeStamp               Error
2019-05-27 10:49:18,418 ERROR  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Job  (3064130e1dccead0b037f193d3699c3b) switched from state FAILING to FAILED.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: json can not be null or empty
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.Utils.notEmpty(Utils.java:256)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.compile(JsonPath.java:424)
    at com.mypkg.subpkg.ControlData$ConnectedStreams.validateJsonPath(ControlData.java:194)
    at com.mypkg.subpkg.ControlData$ConnectedStreams.flatMap1(ControlData.java:178)
    at com.mypkg.subpkg.ControlData$ConnectedStreams.flatMap1(ControlData.java:171)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.co.CoStreamFlatMap.processElement1(CoStreamFlatMap.java:53)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor.processInput(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:238)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.TwoInputStreamTask.run(TwoInputStreamTask.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:300)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here Error message is split into multiple lines to for that I have written java pattern like below:

```
((?m)\\d{4}-[01]\\d-[0-3]\\d\\s[0-2]\\d((:[0-5]\\d)?){2}[\\s\\S]*ERROR[\\s\\S]*[ ]*at [\\s\\S]*)
```

But it returns me all the content of the file.

What should I do to make it work so that it will give me multi-line error message too.

Comment: I see from your stack trace that appear to be trying to apply regex to a JSON string.  Don't do that.  Use a JSON parser instead.

Comment: Didn't get you, this is basically any stack trace file from which I want to extract multiline error message.

Comment: I get _you_ now...you're trying to parse the stack trace itself :-)

Comment: Exactly :) you got it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
((\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3,5})\sERROR.+?(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3,5}))
```

Explantion:

- `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3,5})` - matches the timestamp
- `\sERROR.+?(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3,5})` - does the nongreedy match until you find the next timestamp (Positive Lookahead)
- Also i would like to highlight that you wil have to use `m` option for multiline match while using this regex
- This match will give you nested groups for every match like `[[log, timestamp],[log, timestamp]]`

Comment: This worked but how can I add a timestamp as the key and error message as a value in hashmap?

Comment: That you will have to do programmatically. Every match will have two groups first is error second is timestamp.
You can loop over the list and create a hashmap while looping

Comment: I tried something like this: `map.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));` but key and value both contains an error message.

Comment: What could be the pattern for this type of input `2019-05-27 05:14:36.224Z|app|machine|[XNIO-2 task-11]|ERROR|533a1030-0301-407d-bdbb-569892bded45|||b3b73ff6-3689-4def-a860-9dccd77226d9||9gHJMKox|3|com.app.log.LogAspect:aroundInternal|61|Error occured com.pkg.subpkg.class.getIt(String, Set)`

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern looks off, and also you should be using a pattern in dot all mode, since the portion of the stack trace which you want to capture may span across more one than line.  I suggest using the following regex pattern:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} ERROR.*?(?=\bat\b)
```

This matches a timestamp, followed by `ERROR` and then all content until reaching the first `at`.

Here is a working test script:

```
String input = "2019-05-27 10:49:18,418 ERROR  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Job  (3064130e1dccead0b037f193d3699c3b) switched from state FAILING to FAILED.\njava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: json can not be null or empty\n    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.Utils.notEmpty(Utils.java:256)";
String pattern = "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2},\\d{3} ERROR.*?(?=\\bat\\b)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Output:

```
2019-05-27 10:49:18,418 ERROR  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Job  (3064130e1dccead0b037f193d3699c3b) switched from state FAILING to FAILED.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: json can not be null or empty
```

Comment: It's working only for the input that u hardcoded, if you consider my file then it will print all content including INFO logs too.

Comment: Then make the dot lazy, use `.*?(?=\bat\b`

Comment: Tried same but now it gives single line result including INFO logs too.

Comment: @snoop I can't reproduce your observations, and my answer [is working in this online Java demo](https://rextester.com/WUU44498).

Comment: Slightly modified the input, included INFO logs in between ERROR logs please check, now its printing INFO logs too. https://rextester.com/GAEL82642. Updated.

Comment: Well, I don't have that link, so I can't look at it.